# Short exact sequence split

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

For groups $G$, $H$, and $K$, assume there exists a left-split short exact sequence: $$ 1 \rightarrow K \xrightarrow{\varphi} G \xrightarrow{\psi} H \rightarrow 1$$
Then $\varphi$ is an injective homomorphsim, $\psi$ is a surjective homomorphism, and ${\rm Im}(\varphi) = \ker(\psi)$. Furthermore, there exists a homomorphism $\pi: G \rightarrow K$ such that $\pi \circ \varphi = id_K$.

How can I show that these assumptions imply that

$H \triangleleft G, K \triangleleft G, G = HK,$ and $H \cap K = \{ 1 \}$?

Comment: It is equivalent to show that $G$ is the direct product of $H$ and $K$.

Comment: Well yes, but do my assumptions directly imply that $H \triangleleft G, K \triangleleft G, G = HK,$ and $H \cap K = \{ 1 \}$?

Comment: Almost everything follows from the definition of an exact sequence. Have you tried using that?

Comment: the normality of K in G is from the definition yes, but i stuck on the normality of H in G

Comment: also not sure why the intersection of G H and K is trivial

Comment: @Jordan Reed Neither $K$ nor $H$ are given as subgroups of $G$, so it is inappropriate to speak of any of them as "normal in $G$" or to speak of "their intersection in $G$". And if $K$ does at least embed in $G$ (even so, the non-rigorous claim that $K$ is normal in $G$ should preferably be phrased as "$K$ embeds as a normal subgroup of $G$") so that you might have some grounds of relating it to a subgroup of $G$, that is no longer the case for $H$, at least not upon first sight. *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Jordan Reed *(cont.)* And this is right at the heart of the problem: in your given context, what particular subgroup of $G$ should you be looking at, that relates well to both $H$ and the embedded image $\varphi[K]$?

Answer (score 2):

Before we begin, I would like to set forth the following general relations which we shall refer to in the course of our proof:

1. For any group morphism $f \colon G \to G'$ and any subset $X \subseteq G$, we have that $f^{-1}\left[f[X]\right]=X\mathrm{Ker}f$.
2. For any group morphism $f \colon G \to G'$ and any subgroup $H \leqslant G$, we have the following description for the kernel of the restriction: $\mathrm{Ker}f_{|H}=H \cap \mathrm{Ker}f$.

For convenience I will slightly alter the original notation. Consider the following *exact* sequence:

$$\{1\} \xrightarrow \ F \xrightarrow{f} E \xrightarrow{g} G \xrightarrow{} \{1\} \tag{*}
$$
of groups, where $f$ admits the retraction $h \colon E \to F$. Consider the subgroups $H\colon=\mathrm{Im}f=\mathrm{Ker}g \trianglelefteq E$ and $K\colon=\mathrm{Ker}h \trianglelefteq E$.

The relation $h \circ f=\mathbf{1}_F$ leads to $h[H]=F$, whence by taking inverse images through $h$ we derive $E=h^{-1}[F]=h^{-1}\left[h[H]\right]=HK$ (general relation 1).

Since by definition $\mathrm{Im}f \subseteq H$ we have $\mathbf{1}_F=h \circ f=h_{|H} \circ {}_{H|}f$ (for arbitrary map $k \colon A \to B$ with subsets $M \subseteq A$, $N \subseteq B$ such that $k[M] \subseteq N$, the symbol ${}_{N|}k_{|M}$ denotes the restriction of $k$ between $M$ and $N$). Being the restriction of a map to its image, ${}_{H|}f$ is surjective and since it is the restriction of an injection it continues to be injective. This means that ${}_{H|}f$ is an isomorphism and the previous relation entails that the restriction $h_{|H}=\left({}_{H|}f\right)^{-1}$ is the inverse isomorphism. In particular this means that $h_{|H}$ is injective and we thus have $\{1_E\}=\mathrm{Ker}h_{|H}=K \cap H$ (general relation 2).

At this point we have already established that $H$ and $K$ are mutually supplementary subgroups of $E$, hence $E \approx H \times K \hspace{3pt} (\mathbf{Gr})$. Since ${}_{H|}f$ is an isomorphism it is clear that $F \approx H \hspace{3pt} (\mathbf{Gr})$. Let us also inspect the relation between $K$ and $G$. As $g$ is surjective we have $G=g[E]=g[HK]=g[K]$ ($H$ being the kernel of $g$). Furthermore, $\mathrm{Ker}g_{|K}=H \cap K=\{1_E\}$, which means that the restriction $g_{|K}$ is an isomorphism as well and we thus have $K \approx G \hspace{3pt} (\mathbf{Gr})$.

The previous analysis shows that $E \approx F \times G \hspace{3pt} (\mathbf{Gr})$. Let us remark that given the context there is an explicit way of exhibiting an isomorphism not only between the forementioned groups, but actually between the extensions $(^*)$ given at the beginning and the one below:
$$\{1\} \xrightarrow{} F \xrightarrow{\iota} F \times G \xrightarrow{p} G \xrightarrow{} \{1\},$$
where $\iota$ is the canonical injection given by $\iota(x)=(x, 1_G)$ and $p$ the canonical projection onto the second factor. Let us consider the direct product in restricted sense (also known as the diagonal product) $\varphi\colon=h\underline{\times}g \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(E, F \times G)$. It is straightforward to see that:

1. $\varphi \circ f=(h \circ f) \underline{\times} (g \circ f)=\mathbf{1}_F \underline{\times} \mathbf{0}_{GF}=\iota$ (for arbitrary groups $G$ and $G'$ the symbol $\mathbf{0}_{G'G}$ denotes the *null* morphism from $G$ to $G'$, as the category of groups does indeed have null objects)
2. $p \circ \varphi=g$ by definition of direct products in restricted sense.

This establishes the commutativity of the following diagram:
[image: Commutative diagram]

which means nothing else than that $\varphi$ is indeed a morphism of extensions, hence implicitly an *isomorphism* between $E$ and $F \times G$.

Comment: I do not understand from where this line in your answer is correct "(recall that in general $f^{-1}[f[X]]=X\mathrm{Ker}f$ for any group morphism $f \colon G \to G'$ and any subset $X \subseteq G$)." Could you please clarify that?

Comment: I do not understand how can Ker $f$ intersect H where $H$ is the image of $f$..... here is your statement " $\mathrm{Ker}f_{|H}=H \cap \mathrm{Ker}f$ " ..... could you please explain it?

Comment: $H \nsubset F$ in our case here so how can I intersect it with Ker $f$

Comment: @Smart20 I apologise for creating confusion, What happens here is that my explanatory brackets refer to very general properties/relations valid in *any* context of group morphisms, however due to a limited set of preferred options for notation, I used the same symbols $f$, $G$ etc to express those general properties as the symbols already used in the specific context of the short exact sequence problem. In other words, I am using the same symbols to refer to different objects in different contexts, however I shall rectify this. Do please take a look.

Comment: Could you please clarify your point of view more here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842943/short-exact-sequence-split-answer-illustration?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Smart20 Before I start addressing your list of questions from the new posting, I will edit it so as to include the current form of my edited answer that lies here on this page.

Comment: Do whatever you like.

Comment: How $E=h^{-1}[F]$ ?  Can you explain please ?

Comment: @Masmath This is elementary set theory: in general, given an arbitrary map $f \colon A \to B$ it will always be the case that $f^{-1}[B]=A$ (the inverse image through any map of the codomain of that map is precisely the definition domain of the same map).

Comment: ohh, it was simple. I perhaps thought other way. Thanks